# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when calling a dynamically added method with SEL as it's second parameter

Tags: objective-c

So I tried to add a method dynamically  to a class. The IMP of the method was constructed with a block

```
typedef void (^newMethodBlockType)(id, SEL, id);

newMethodBlockType newMethodBlock =  ^void(id _self, SEL _cmd, id newVal){
    // do something
};

IMP newMethodImp = imp_implementationWithBlock(newMethodBlock);

NSString *methodName = @"newMethod:";
SEL       newMethodSel = NSSelectorFromString(methodName);

Class clz = objc_getClass("MyClass");

class_addMethod(clz, newMethodSel, newMethodImp, "v@:@");
```

The call to class_addMethod returns with no error. But when I call the new method I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and the debugger takes me to the line where the block was declared.

I think that for some reason the block isn't retained.

Adding:

```
newMethodBlock = [newMethodBlock copy];
```

doesn't seem to help.

EDIT:
I managed to get it to work by changing the declaration of the block to not include the selector as the second parameter.

```
newMethodBlockType newMethodBlock =  ^void(id _self, id newVal){
    // do something
};
```

Now it seems to be working all right, but why?
Doesn't the selector always get sent to a method.

This method was used as a setter for a property and was called by

```
[task setValue:[NSNumber numberWithLong:1001] forKey:@"myProperty"];
```

Is it that when a setter is called via setValue:forKey: the selector isn't sent to the setter method?

Comment: Can you post your project on GitHub?

Comment: I can't post the project, but I can add more code to the question.
What would you like to see?

Comment: What you did in the block?

Comment: Even when I just outputted some string with NSLog, it still crashed

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `imp_implementationWithBlock()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418587-imp_implementationwithblock?language=objc):

> The signature of `block` should be `method_return_type ^(id self, self, method_args …)`. The selector of the method is not available to `block`.

I actually think that second `self` is an error in the documentation, but it's clear about the absence of `_cmd`.